# Repeat a number in string twice using sed command

Tags: linux, unix, sed, terminal

Let's say I have `hell0 w0rld`, I want it to become `hell00 w0rld`.
I tried `sed s/0/00/`, but that only replaces `0`, it wouldn't work for `he1lo wor1d(he11lo wor1d)`, what can I do so that it replaces any first digit, instead of just `0`?

Comment: Do you want to replace the number (as per title) or digit (as per text)?

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't want to match just `0`, but any digit, you want to use `[0-9]`. This stands for "any one of the digits 0-9". You put this in parentheses to "capture" it, and in the replacement string, you can add backrefences:

```
$ sed 's/\([0-9]\)/\1\1/' <<< "he1lo wor1d"
he11lo wor1d
```

If you want to repeat the first *number* (as per the title) and not just digit, you append `\+` to your character class. This stands for "one or more of these":

```
$ sed 's/\([0-9]\+\)/\1\1/' <<< "he12o wor1d"
he1212o wor1d
```

An alternative to the backreferences `\1`, which match the capture group `/(.../)`, would be to use `&`, which stands for the complete match, i.e.,

```
sed 's/[0-9]/&&/' <<< "he1lo wor1d"
```

and

```
sed 's/[0-9]\+/&&/' <<< "he12lo wor1d"
```

where the `/(.../)` are not needed any longer.

Comment: Perhaps `sed 's/[0-9]/&&/' file` is a little easier on the eye?